# Refresh a textview when click a radio button Android

Tags: android, radio-button, refresh, textview

I need to refresh a texview when i click a radio button. My textview contains the free memory info and i want that when i click the radio button i use to clear the RAM cache the textview refreshes and so i can see in that moment the free RAM without exit the application and enter it again.I found this example

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lastRefreshed);
tv.setText("Blah: " + time);
view.invalidate();  // for refreshment
```

Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: "free memory info". What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register click event for radio-button.

```
 RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
 rb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // refresh the textview here
    }
});
```

Comment: But is it correct `view.invalidate();` for refresh the textview?

Comment: @End.Game Do `tv.invalidate()`, view.invalidate() will invalidate whole activity view

Comment: Thank you so much. When i go home i try ;)